# reactjs/react-router-dom: Browserrouter routing question

Tags: reactjs, react-router

this is probably a very simple issue but I cannot find an answer from my searching.

I am writing an app using ReactJs and am using react-router-dom's browserrouter for routing.

When I enter '/login' as URL, the below code will return Profile component, instead of intended Login component. How do I ensure that this will land to Login component as intended?

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./routes/Home";
import Profile from "./routes/Profile";
import Post from "./routes/Post"
import Login from "./routes/Login"

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/login" exact={true} component={Login}/>
        <Route path="/r/:postid" exact={true} component={Post}/>
        <Route path="/:username" exact={true} component={Profile}/>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: for more info, https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Switch` instead, as it Renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location.

Example:

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/login" exact={true} component={Login}/> 
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```